# Smoothing out missing values in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am using the dataset - https://data.ca.gov/dataset/covid-19-cases/resource/7e477adb-d7ab-4d4b-a198-dc4c6dc634c9 to look into covid cases and deaths in California.

As well as looking at cases/deaths by ethnicity I have grouped the data to give a total column of cases deaths per day. I also used the lag function to give a daily case / death amount.

However on 2 days in December (23rd and 30th) no increment to the cases or deaths columns were made so the daily cases and deaths read 0. The following day the data is 'caught up' with an extra large amount being added on, clearly the sum of the 2 days. (I suspect Christmas and New Year are the causes)

Is there a way of fixing this data? e.g. splitting the double days measurement into half and populating the cells with this, and then retrospectively altering the daily cases and daily deaths figures?
Hopefully the screenshots will clarify what i mean.

Here is the code I have used:

```
demog_eth <- (read.csv ("./Data/case_demographics_ethnicity.csv", header = T, sep = ","))
demog_eth$date <-as.Date(demog_eth$date)

#Create a DF with total daily information 
total_stats <- data.frame(demog_eth$cases,demog_eth$deaths,demog_eth$date)
names(total_stats) <- c('cases', 'deaths', 'date')
total_stats <- total_stats %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(cases = sum(cases), deaths = sum(deaths))

#Add daily cases and deaths by computing faily difference in totals
##Comment - use lag to look at previous rows
total_stats <- total_stats %>%
  mutate(daily_cases = cases-lag(cases),
         daily_deaths = deaths-lag(deaths))
```

[image: DataFrame showing problem rows]

The top paragraph of text in the image says cases and deaths. It should say Daily Cases and Daily Deaths. Apologies

Comment: Be careful.  It sounds to me as if your datset records number of deaths reported rather than number of people who died on each day.  This means you will have seasonal effects in many places, not just on public holidays.  In the UK, for example, reported deaths are always "low" on Saturday and Sunday and "high" on Monday and Tuesday.  In Italy, I believe, if a COVID death is not reported on the day after it occurred, it is NEVER counted as a COVID death...

Comment: But to answer your question, using `lag` and `lead` on `cases` and then recalculating `daily_cases` (And the same for `deaths` and `daily_deaths` [sic]) should give you what you want.

Comment: @Limey - Not sure I understand the lag/lead bit. I generate daily cases / deaths by using lag / lead on the cases / deaths columns respectively.

Comment: `...  %>% mutate(cases=ifelse(daily_cases==0, (lead(cases) - lag(cases))/2, cases)`.  Untested code.  In other words, if there are no reports on a given day, split the cases reported tomorrow between today and tomorrow.    Then recalculate daily cases as well.  Note, this only works if you don't have two or more consecutive days on which no cases are reported.

Comment: @Limey - I see where you're going with that. It needed a little tweak. It solves the empty daily cases issue but still leaves the (lead) daily case as a double days reporting. Meaning the daily cases and total cases no longer match up. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(col=seq(1:100), col2=seq(from=1, to=200, by=2))
df[c(33, 2),] <- 0

zeros <- as.integer(rownames(df[df$col == 0,])) # detect rows with 0

for (i in zeros){
df[i,"col"] <- 0.5 * df[i+1,"col"]
df[i+1,"col"] <- 0.5 * df[i+1,"col"]
}
```

Sorry, that I used own simple example data. But the mechanism should work if adapted.

Comment: For some reason the zeros came back wiht just 1 2 3 in it for me so I modified that a bit. 

emptycases <- as.integer(which(total_stats$daily_cases == 0)) # detect rows with 0
   
for (i in emptycases){
  total_stats[i,"daily_cases"] <- floor(0.5 * total_stats[i+1,"daily_cases"])
  total_stats[i+1,"daily_cases"] <- ceiling(0.5 * total_stats[i+1,"daily_cases"])
  total_stats[i,"daily_deaths"] <- floor(0.5 * total_stats[i+1,"daily_deaths"])
  total_stats[i+1,"daily_deaths"] <- ceiling(0.5 * total_stats[i+1,"daily_deaths"])
}

Worked perfectly for me. Thanks, accepted